# Ubuntu 20.04, running HDMI to display. Switching display inputs to another box and back results in a black screen

Tags: 20.04, display, hdmi, 4k-monitor

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04, and HDMI to my display via a 4K switch. I have another machine connected to the same switch. If I switch the inputs to that box and back, I end up with a black screen in Ubuntu.

The monitor shows the input type for a second or two, then goes to standby, and repeats; I have to manually reboot to recover. I tested using several HDMI cables, even an optic fiber cable, same issue. I tested running HDMI directly, and when I switch inputs on the monitor I have the same issue.

Now, the switching between HDMI inputs works just fine under Windows on both boxes. It also works fine if I run DP to the monitor from Ubuntu; I can switch inputs on the monitor without losing the display when I return to Ubuntu. However, I need to run the systems in another room and send the display via HDMI, hence why I want to solve this issue.

So, I suspect the issue lies with Ubuntu 20.04 and HDMI. I tried using both Nouveau and NVIDIA 460 drivers to no avail. My graphics card is an EVGA RTX 2070 XC Ultra Gaming, and the monitor is a Samsung U32H850 32" 4K UHD Quantum Dot Monitor.

Does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same issue here. But my monitor is a Samsung U32J590 32'' 4K UHD and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950. Everything works fine until you change the source on the monitor.

> neofetch
> OS: Ubuntu Hirsute Hippo (developmen
> Kernel: 5.11.0-13-generic
> Uptime: 16 mins
> Packages: 1908 (dpkg), 10 (snap)
> Shell: bash 5.1.4
> Resolution: 3840x2160
> CPU: Intel i7-3770 (8) @ 4.100GHz
> GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950
> Memory: 2273MiB / 7896MiB

I solved the problem changing the driver of NVIDIA from 460 to 390
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFAs3.png)

Now everything is working fine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I'll try this today and accept it if it works.

Comment: I rolled back the driver to 450, and this worked for me. Thanks again.